# Persisting dynamic data in the database for workflow execution

Tags: java, sql-server, database, database-design

We have a Java application that is used to schedule and execute multiple workflows that are independent of each other. With each workflow execution, there can be 'n' number of variables associated with it whose values depend on the source data that is used for that workflow execution.

So, let us say, for workflow W1, we have 10 variables associated with it. Similarly, for workflow W2, we have 8 variables and for workflow W3, we have 6 variables. The requirement is to persist these variables information (for each workflow execution) somewhere so that, after execution, the business user can track these variables in the application dashboard and search for that information.

**Approach 1**: Initially, we thought to create a database table to track these variables - one per workflow. But this idea was dropped because it can lead to a large number of database tables in the application (same as a number of workflows in the application). Moreover, out of 10 variables associated with the workflow, the user can decide to track 5 variables or 8 variables or all 10 (depending on what it wants). So, it is difficult to keep altering the columns of the database table (being used for variables tracking) depending on the variables that user has opted for tracking.

**Approach 2**: Later on, we decided to have a single database table with generic column names like var1, var2, var 3...upto var 25 along with columns for workflowId, workflowName etc. For each workflow, we maintain the mapping of the actual variable name that needs to be tracked with the column name in an XML format. So, for a workflow that needs to track 4 variables, we will have an XML like:

```
<variables>
    <variable name="var1">CustomerId</variable>
    <variable name="var2">PolicyNumber</variable>
    <variable name="var3">ReferenceCode</variable>
    <variable name="var4">Type</variable>
</variables>
```

At runtime, we will insert the workflow execution variable data in the database table used for tracking. While displaying the data in the dashboard, we will parse the above XML, map the data from the database table and display it. But this approach looks bit convoluted and doesn't sound the best approach.

**My question is**: Is Approach 2 fine or there is a better way to persist this information? Are there any recommendations that shall be followed in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a vertical approach to creating a table to persist the variables.  Your table only needs three columns to handle any number of workflows:

```
WorkflowID    VariableNumber    VariableValue
```

`WorkflowID` is the unique ID of the workflow you are holding the variables for.
`VariableNumber` is the ordinal number of a variable used by that workflow.

(the two columns above form the primary key of your table, btw)

`VariableValue` is the value you are holding in the table for that variable/workflow.

So if a workflow has 10 variables, then there will be 10 rows in the table for that `WorkflowID`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice suggestion. The only concern that I see here is that for each workflow execution, it will have multiple rows (depending on # of variables). It may lead to large number of rows in the table. Thoughts?

Comment: My thought is this will be fine.  On such a narrow table, only 3 columns, and with the clustered index on WorkflowID & VariableNumber, performance will be super fast, even if you get into billions of rows.

Comment: Allerman: In our case, one common scenario is that one variable can have multiple values. For example, if a Purchase Order file is being processed by the workflow, it may have multiple orders numbers that need to be tracked. So, a workflow instance can have multiple variables - so does it make sense to remove unique constraint (or primary key) on WorkflowID and VariableNumber column? If yes, does it impact the performance when the tables grows large?

Comment: It does not make sense to me to not have a unique constraint.  How do you keep track of which order number is which?   It would make sense to me if an order had an "OrderNumber1" and "OrderNumber2" etc, but not multiple variables all named "OrderNumber".

Comment: I understand your point here, thanks! But is there any other recommended way of persisting variable that can have multiple values?

Comment: I don't know of any other ways.

Comment: Thank you! Do you prefer using NoSQL for persisting such information?

Comment: I have never used NoSQL.